# Navigation between two points

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show route between two points, i know the latitudes and longitudes of both points and want to show directions and route line between these. How i can do this in android google maps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Direction API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

You get a JSON result which contain all information for direction from one point to another point.

If you have these two points:

Point 1: (48.11111,2.11111)

Point 2: (48.55555,2.66666)

your request is like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=48.11111,2.11111&destination=48.55555,2.66666&mode=driving&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This URL return a JSON with all steps

Comment: here i can use android api key or i should generate another for this?

Comment: And after you create your api key, you need to go in "Services" (left nav) and activate the "Directions API". After that, you can test the URL request in your browser